# Random text being returned as a number after being passed through Number() function

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, type-conversion, numbers

Can someone help me understand why the string values entered in an html form are returning as a number when I use `typeof`, even when the original value is very specifically a string?

Below is a link to a pic of two values input first as random text (`yyy`) then as as a number (`999`), followed by their "types" before and after passing the values through the `Number()` function. Before they pass through the `Number()` function both are strings, as expected.

However, after passing the intentional string (`yyy`) through the `Number()` function I expected that ["if you pass in a string with random text in it, you’ll get `NaN`, an acronym for 'Not a Number.' "](https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/)

But, instead, it's saying that **both** (`999`)'s and (`yyy`)'s values are of the type `"number"`.

[image of form and console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Ym1.jpg)

Comment: `typeof NaN === 'number`'. You check for `NaN` with `isNaN`, not `typeof`.

Comment: ...but if I pass a string through a ```Number()``` function, for example:  ```Number("this value is a random string of text and not a number")``` it's supposed to return as NaN --as far as I understand. Because it didn't ```isNaN()``` didn't work when I attempted to use it for validation. I ended up having to put the values into a mathematical equation ```(value / 1)``` in order to get ```isNaN``` to function the way I expected it to.

Comment: It does return `NaN`. Without seeing the full code you’re using to try it it’s not clear where the issue is, but if you open up your console and run `isNaN(Number("this value is a random string of text and not a number"))` it should be `true`.

Comment: Yep, I see what you're saying, now. Thank you!